# Problem building C project after upgrading project from Visual Studio 2008 to 2010

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008, compiler-errors, upgrade

I have a solution (all C programs) in Visual Studio 2008. I am trying to upgrade it to VS 2010. Most of the projects build just fine in 2010, but one project is getting the error below as a result of this line:

```
#include <iphlpapi.h>
```

Errors from Output Window:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\iphlpapi.h(390): error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier 'Statistics'
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\iphlpapi.h(390): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'Statistics'
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\iphlpapi.h(390): error C2059: syntax error : ';'
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\iphlpapi.h(390): error C2059: syntax error : ','
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\iphlpapi.h(392): error C2059: syntax error : ')'
>   ... more of the same ...

The erroring block in iphlpapi.h looks like this:

```
line 386: #if (NTDDI_VERSION >= NTDDI_XP)
line 387: ULONG
line 388: WINAPI
line 389: GetIpStatisticsEx(
line 390:     __out PMIB_IPSTATS Statistics,
line 391:     __in  ULONG Family
line 392:     );
```

Why would this compile successfully in VS 2008 but not VS 2010?

Thanks for any guidance.

---

### Additional comment

I added this code to the module:

```
#pragma message("NTDDI_VERSION = " _CRT_STRINGIZE(NTDDI_VERSION))
#pragma message("NTDDI_XP      = " _CRT_STRINGIZE(NTDDI_XP))
#if (NTDDI_VERSION >= NTDDI_XP)
  #pragma message("compile this")
#else
  #pragma message("don't compile this")
#endif
```

The compile output was this:

> NTDDI_VERSION = 0x04000000
>   NTDDI_XP      = NTDDI_XP
>   compile this

So `NTDDI_XP` isn't even defined!

Comment: Are you sure your update is to VS2010? This problem can happen (I know) in VS2017 (and sometimes VS2019) but I cannot offer a suggestion as to how to fix it in VS2010.

Comment: I backed up the 2008 solution, and then opened the solution in VS2010 and let it go through the upgrade process.  And yes, I am sure it is VS2010.

Comment: OK, well right now I don't have access to the PC with my VS2010 projects on but, just guessing: It's a language conformity issue; maybe go through the "C\C++" settings in your project properties and see if you can 'reset' them to a looser/earlier standard.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I looked at every possible project property but could not see any that might be relevant.  Maybe I need a different SDK?

Comment: That SDK (I think) works in VS2017 - so long as you turn of "Conformance Mode" in the C++ settings. But I don't know what the equivalent is (if any) in VS2010. You could maybe look for a newer version - but be warned, new stuff may require VS2015 or later!!

Comment: Or set `NTDDI_VERSION` to less than the value of `NTDDI_XP` to avoid the header block(s)?

Comment: @Adrian - thanks for getting me thinking.  I added this before the #include `#define NTDDI_XP 0x5000000` so the code block in question is not compiled. Now the project builds. See my Additional Comments above. Too complicated to add to a regular comment.

Comment: Always glad to help!